# How can I stop Android from automatically searching a term when I choose it from my search history?

Tags: search

Currently if I search for something like "Why am I so awesome," then at a later time I want to elaborate on that search and start typing in "Why am..." my search history will show the previously searched term.  When I click on the term it automatically searches for it.  I don't want it to automatically search for it, I just want the term I click on to populate the search field so I can edit as I please before actually searching, for example, I'd like to be able to click on the aforementioned search term "Why am I so awesome" and add "everyday" without having to retype the whole things.  It's not that big of a deal in a google search because I can just wait for the results and edit the search field, however on a market search, the search field disappears when it searches and I have to start all over again.

**Edit:** To me this seems to be an Android issue, not a hardware issue but to preempt any more hardware specific solutions that don't apply to me, I have a Moto Droid 1 on 2.2.

Comment: +1. Glad you asked the question. I will need to start using the trackpad when using search history...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The anonym with the vague answer is correct, just not nearly complete.  For keyboard-less phones (like my N1), the trackball or trackpad can be used to scroll down the list of suggestions, and that will enter them into the text field for editing.  For most phones with a hardware keyboard like your Droid, use the d-pad next to the keyboard to select the suggestion for editing (some of them still retain a trackball or trackpad).  Once you have the correct entry in the search box, tap it to continue editing.

BTW, I just discovered this, and it's going to make my life a lot easier.

Comment: That's bothered me a few times too, it's annoying to find that the answer is to use the trackpad/ball when I'm on a phone that doesn't have one (Samsung Galaxy S). I thought about it when I upgraded from the HTC Magic, but at the time I could count the number of times I used the trackball on one hand. Seems it does have a use after all :(

Comment: But nothing for those of us with no trackball or d-pad, like the X? :(

Answer (score 7):

If you update to the latest version of "Google Search" in the Market, it includes a pencil icon next to each item in the search history, for this exact problem. Tapping the pencil loads the search term into the search box, but doesn't initiate a search for it.

Comment: That is great, I never noticed that.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work on searches initiated directly from the Market, Maps... but it works from the search widget.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a pencil when I google search and I don't see any Google Search app in Marketplace. I'm on eclair (Motorola xt720).

Comment: I think you need to be on froyo for this.